# rkhunter results - /usr/bin/ldd modification date weirdness!? Is this a problem?

Tags: rkhunter

I ran rkhunter as usual and got this result;

```
Warning: The file properties have changed:
         File: /usr/bin/ldd
         Current hash: 7e193a7e34656a73e85b88e0b8e0e81d66b67878
         Stored hash : e90c14c292bd796fbb1191fdf2ad41ffa820b2d4
         Current inode: 1585530    Stored inode: 1581256
         Current file modification time: 1490300326 (23-Mar-2017 20:18:46)
         Stored file modification time : 1464258616 (26-May-2016 11:30:16)
```

However, I think the modification date is before the last time I ran rkhunter, so I should have seen this the last time I ran it, but it didn't show up. Is there any way to find out when you last ran rkhunter? Also I tried reinstalling the package which /usr/bin/ldd is associated with (libc-bin) but the modification date of /usr/bin/ldd stayed the same despite re-installation. what's going on here? Do I need to be concerned about a compromised system?

Comment: Make sure that you've updated rkhunter's database, otherwise it might not have the latest hashes

Comment: thought that was the point of rkhunter though? I scan and update it (`propupd`) every time I do an update or install anything. If I just update it now then surely it will just make the possible vulnerability appear normal?